# Is <style> inside body supported by the majority of browsers

Tags: html, css

I did make a stupid mistake where I placed a style tag in the body to make it really clear what part of the page it styled.

My question is: can I let it be like that or is it really important to move it to the head, to ensure that most major browsers will display the page properly?

I know that it's supposed to go into the head, but we're talking about a 100 files and if most major browsers supports this, I estimates that it wouldn't be worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is supported.
However it is a best practice to not to use directly inside of the HTML tags, use CSS files instead:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps

If you have a lot of similar elements, where you want to use the same styles, you should use a separate CSS files and use class/id tags inside of your HTML, and call it in the HTML file.

Check out some advice from mozilla development:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Organizing

Comment: Thank you! I wont edit all the files then. It's because I'm styling a page where some languages have really long words, so I have to make manual styles per page. But thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

It will work but it's not best practice.  Ideally if you want to include inline styling / non render blocking CSS, try to include the  tag just before the closing head tag.